# Limit tk Button to spawn open only 1 new window at a time

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a python application using Tkinter.
The purpose of the application is to allow the user to pick a date from a calendar.

The user have to click on a button to spawn a new window,
The user then select the date and updates the value in the mainframe.

I have coded it:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    """ Allows user to pick a date """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label_a01 = tk.Label(text = 'Selected date is:')

        self.var_selected_date = tk.StringVar(value = "Noting selected")
        self.label_selected_date = tk.Label(textvariable = self.var_selected_date)

        self.button_a01 = tk.Button(self,
            text="Select the first day", command = self.select_a_date)
        self.button_a02 = tk.Button(self,
            text="Select the last day", command = self.select_a_date)

        self.label_a01.pack()
        self.label_selected_date.pack()
        self.button_a01.pack(pady = 5)
        self.button_a02.pack(pady = 5)

    def select_a_date(self):
        self.window01 = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.label_b01 = tk.Label(self.window01, text = 'Please select a date from the calendar')
        self.button_b01 = tk.Button(self.window01, text="01 Jan 2022", command = lambda: self.update_date_to_mainframe(self.button_a01, "01 Jan 2022"))
        self.button_b02 = tk.Button(self.window01, text="31 Dec 2022", command = lambda: self.update_date_to_mainframe(self.button_a02, "31 Dec 2022"))

        self.label_b01.pack(pady = 5)
        self.button_b01.pack(pady = 5)
        self.button_b02.pack(pady = 5)

    def update_date_to_mainframe(self, widget, text_to_update):
        widget.config(text = text_to_update)

def main():
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

However, if the user click the button multiple times, it will open many new windows.
Is there a way to limit only 1 new Toplevel window that can be opened from the button press?

[image: How to prevent multiple Toplevel window spawn?]

Comment: Usually its a simple logic, but in this case since both function needs a window opened, it is not so simple. Unless you are willing to split up the function for both buttons

Comment: Make the window a modal dialog.

Comment: I have tried "modal concept" by using MyParentWindow.wm_attributes("-disabled", False). 

but I got an error "must be -alpha, -fullscreen, -modified, -notify, -titlepath, -topmost, -transparent, or -type". Is the modal dialog still valid in tk?

Comment: Just add `self.window01.grab_set()` at the end of `select_a_date()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to acw1668 for suggesting modal dialogs.
Found an answer somewhere on reddit:
(credits to socal_nerdtastic)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

try: #python3 imports
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError: #python3 failed, try python2 imports
    import Tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="this is the main frame")
        lbl.pack()

        btn = tk.Button(self, text='click me', command=self.open_popup)
        btn.pack()

    def open_popup(self):
        print("runs before the popup")
        Popup(self)
        print("runs after the popup closes")

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    """modal window requires a master"""
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        lbl = tk.Label(self, text="this is the popup")
        lbl.pack()

        btn = tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.destroy)
        btn.pack()

        # The following commands keep the popup on top.
        # Remove these if you want a program with 2 responding windows.
        # These commands must be at the end of __init__
        self.transient(master) # set to be on top of the main window
        self.grab_set() # hijack all commands from the master (clicks on the main window are ignored)
        master.wait_window(self) # pause anything on the main window until this one closes

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    window = Main(root)
    window.pack()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```